# Forgot to take backup before change Name Server

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

I host my website on `[SERVER A]` but there, I face many issue in server. So i change Name server regarding `[SERVER B]` and Host site on that. but I forgot to take a backup of my site from `[SERVER A]`. Now what I have to do for getting data back ?

Comment: Connect directly to the ip of SERVER A, or edit your hosts file to point it back.

Comment: Yes, just connect via FTP using the IP to take your backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to access the server via ssh/http if you know the ip address.
like: `http://87.57.45.2:port` or `ftp://87.57.45.2:port` (both work in the browser)

If you have an ftp client you should be able to connect directly to the server, using port 21/22.

if that doesn't work you can try to contact the support of the hoster.

Worst case your data is lost.

Comment: I have an IP of that, can i connect via FTP ?

Comment: Currently I use windows, and Server is Linux. I have full ftp detail of that

Comment: ok, thank you very much, but what if i want to take database, bcos my site on wordpres

Comment: Thank you for help me out Theolodis